# log retention bytes per topic not working with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I tried setting the log.retention.bytes per topic by using the below command

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic app.test.client --config retention.bytes=10485760`

Verified the config setting by doing a

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic 
app.test.client 
Topic:app.test.client   PartitionCount:3     ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:retention.bytes=10485760
    Topic: app.test.client  Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
    Topic: app.test.client  Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,2   Isr: 0,2
    Topic: app.test.client  Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 1,0
```

I have set my retention bytes to 10MB -> 10485760. But my log files were growing even after 10MB.

```
$du -hs /mnt/kafka/logs/*
128M    /mnt/kafka/logs/app.test.client-1
128M    /mnt/kafka/logs/app.test.client-2
```

Version
 Kafka - 0.8.2.1

How to properly set this setting per topic ?

Answer (score 4):

Kafka retention is made on a segment level. Meaning, when Kafka exceeds the retention boundaries (time or size) it will look for the segments to delete, in order to get back in the retention boundaries. In cases where `retention.bytes` is smaller than `segment.bytes`, you may hit a situation where the is only one segment, which is also the current used segment, so deletion process may work not exactly as expected.

Try to set `segment.bytes` to a value smaller than `retention.bytes`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `log.retention.bytes` doesn't impose a hard limit on a topic/partition size, but rather signal to Kafka when to delete the oldest segment file(s) that are above the value you set this property to.

Comment: As the default segment size is 5G, there will be no segment candidate for deletion before one partition have at least 5G of data.